# Kissme/Kotlin Multiplatform: Unresolved reference: netguru, Unresolved reference: Kissme

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm currently working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project (Kotlin 1.3.50, Gradle 3.6.0-beta04) and want to use the [Kissme](https://github.com/netguru/Kissme) Storage library.
It works on Android as expected, but trying to compile on a Mac for the iOS target,  I get

> Unresolved reference: netguru

and

> Unresolved reference: Kissme

It's mentioned on GitHub, that publishing to maven local could help. But after fetching the git repository, I can't build the library, because there is missing a secret.gradle file.

How can I bring it to work? Is anybody else using this library?

In app's build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    commonMain {
        dependencies {
            implementation 'com.netguru.kissme:common:0.2.5'
        }
    }
    androidMain {
        dependencies {
            implementation 'com.netguru.kissme:android:0.2.5'
        }
    }
    iosMain {
        dependencies {
            implementation 'com.netguru.kissme:ios:0.2.5'
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm encountering this same problem. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I removed that library from my dependencies.

Comment: OK, yeah, same here. Shame; it looks promising, but the developer doesn't seem to be maintaining it.